# How to write to USB not showing up as Serial device

Tags: java, serial-port, usb

As a pet project I want to get data out of a Glucose Meter over USB. But the device won't show up as a serial device. I need help figuring out what my next step would be, documentation and/or examples are very welcome.

This is my first take at communicating with something over USB.

I only get these devices listed as serial devices from [nrjavaserial](http://code.google.com/p/nrjavaserial/) (I'm on a Mac):

```
/dev/cu.Bluetooth-PDA-Sync
/dev/tty.Bluetooth-Modem
```

but if I run the command below I can see information about the device:

```
$ system_profiler SPUSBDataType

Hub:
      Product ID: 0x2513
      Vendor ID: 0x0424  (SMSC)
      Version:  b.b3
      Speed: Up to 480 Mb/sec
      Location ID: 0xfd100000 / 2
      Current Available (mA): 500
      Current Required (mA): 2

        Abbott Stereo Plug Cable:

          Product ID: 0x3410
          Vendor ID: 0x1a61  (Abbott Diabetes Care)
          Version: 1,01
          Speed: Up to 12 Mb/sec
          Manufacturer: Abbott Labs
          Location ID: 0xfd120000 / 4
          Current Available (mA): 500
          Current Required (mA): Unknown (Device has not been configured)
```

When I tested the similar commands in Linux (lsusb and ls /dev/ttyS*) and it is not listed as a Serial device there neither which makes me think that I'm missing something obvious.

I've seen an example of someone using C# and Serial USB to communicate with a similar device ([The-Beginnings-of-a-Glucose-Meter-Downloader](http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/articles/SweetSpot-The-Beginnings-of-a-Glucose-Meter-Downloader)) which makes me believe that I should be able to do the same with this device.

Comment: Not all devices expose themselves as a serial port.  What are the compatible IDs that the device lists?

Comment: Not following exactly what you mean. Are you referring to a listing of /dev/tty* or the ids in the listing above under Abbott Stereo Plug cable? (he actual device, cable is a stereo plug to usb)

Comment: I don't know where to find this under Linux, but under Windows there is a place for "Compatible IDs" for USB devices.  This would be for your cable.  Although, now that you mention that your USB device is really a cable adapter, I suspect that it actually is a USB/serial adapter.  Have you tried all of the usual drivers for PL2303 and what not?  It may be easier just to make your own cable.  It's probably 3.3V serial on the device.

Comment: Well, I got a brand new cable from Abbott and it is a stereo plug to USB cable. I do not think a new cable would help in this case. I think it is rather a question of how I can communicate with devices that don't show up as serial devices. If I can send "raw" data to some tty and how to figure out which tty to use.

Comment: No, listen, it doesn't work that way.  What you need is a serial driver for that cable of yours.  If you don't have one, you can't use it.  It's that simple.  What you are proposing is writing your own driver.  If you *really* want to do that, then you need to rephrase your question.  That cable of yours is not just a cable, it is a USB device of some kind, likely a USB to 3.3V serial adapter.  To use it, you need the drivers that expose the virtual serial device to your OS.

Comment: Thank you for you patience, I think I'm starting to get it now. I did another try in Linux and got /dev/ttyUSB0 to show up (using `sudo modprobe usbserial vendor=0x1a61 product=0x3410`). So it might be that the drivers I tried for my Mac is not detecting it (FDTI). I tried writing to the port with cutecom [using this protocol](http://www.flupzor.nl/protocol.html) but I got nothing back so I'm not quite there yet. I did a bit of reading on the cable and it is a rs-232 compatible cable. [looks like this](http://www.celeritous.com/estore/sites/default/files/imagecache/product_full/freestyle.jpg)

Comment: Also found out that the device is a TUS3410 USB to Serial adapter. So I guess I can take it from here, thank you for your help. :) For anyone reading this afterwards. Here are the [unofficial TUS3410 drivers for MacOSX](http://e2e.ti.com/support/interface/digital_interface/m/videos__files/198722.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was to, as Brad suggested, find out the correct USB Driver. In my case the productId was 0x3410 which is the TUSB3410 Serial to USB adapter cable.

Here is what I did to finally get a working Serial port in Linux:
`sudo modprobe ti_usb_3410_5052 vendor_3410=0x1a61 product_3410=0x3410`

After that I could send the command mem into my Abbott Freestyle Lite and get the readings back, very nice.

There is also an [unofficial Mac OS X driver](http://e2e.ti.com/support/interface/digital_interface/m/videos__files/198722.aspx) that I have not tried yet.

Comment: Is the ID of the Abbot Freestyle Lite device included in the readings? I get something that looks like an ID, but I'm not sure... :)

Comment: This topic is two years old. I do not remember what the listing looked like.